How do I adjust the swiftUI menu to display the checkmark on the left of the selected option?
Currently the checkmark is displaying to the right of whatever option is selected even though it comes first in the HStack. However, I would like for it to be displayed to the left. Thank you for the help and please let me know if you need any clarification.
    public struct DropDownRow<TitleContent: View, SubtitleContent: View>: View {
        private let titleContent: TitleContent
        private let subtitleContent: SubtitleContent
        private let menuOptions: [String]?
        @Binding private var selectedIndex: Int
        private var onSelection: ((Int, String) -> Void)?
        private var item: String?
        
        public var body: some View {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    titleContent
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                    subtitleContent
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                }
                Spacer()
                Menu {
                    if let options = menuOptions {
                        ForEach(options.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                            Button {
                                self.selectedIndex = index
                                if let type = item {
                                    self.onSelection?(index, type)
                                }
                            } label: {
                                HStack{
                                    if index == selectedIndex {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    }
                                    Text(options[index])
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                            .resizable()
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 16, height: 16, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 16)
                    .padding([.trailing, .vertical], 6)
                }
            }
            .padding(16)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
            .noListSeparators()
        }

Ive tried to use a picker with the style set to ".menu" but it doesnt update my selected index. As far as I could tell the only way to detect the change was through onReceive?

This question is similar to: How to put checkmark when Menu item selected SwiftUI. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

use picker inside menu, as explained in linked question
